# Use an SVG as background to an anchor element

Tags: html, css, svg, web, tabs

I just started out with web development and am trying to build a simple tabbed website. I need an svg to fit perfectly behind an anchor element for all screen sizes but it shrinks down at lower sizes.
Here's my HTML:

```
            <div id="seconddiv">
                <h1>Example</h1>
                <nav>
                    <a class="uls" href="index.html"><p>HOME</p></a>
                    <a class="ul" href="booking.html"><p>BOOK NOW</p></a>
                    <a class="ul" href="contact.html"><p>CONTACT US</p></a>
                </nav>  
            </div>
```

The CSS goes like this:

```
nav a {
text-align: center;
float: left;
width: 28.3%;
margin: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%;
}
.uls {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/tab.svg") no-repeat center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

This is the svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 957 286"
style="enable-background:new 0 0 957 286;" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path id="Selector" style="opacity:0.5;"   
d="M0.5,0.351l0.042,0.083c68.195,1.743,84.244,55.248,97.075,
124.907l28.816,124.17c3.923,19.925,16.566,36.839,
36.814,36.839h628.131c20.248,0,33.468-16.507,
36.814-36.839h- 0.009L857,125.342
c13.045-70.825,29.376-124.99,100.5-124.99H0.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Here's what it looks at standard size:
[Standard Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQOJX.png)

Here's the reduced size:
[Reduced Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztyrr.png)

Comment: Are any of the widths or the paddings on the `a` elements relative to the screen width (i.e. in percents)?

Comment: Does tab.svg have a preserveAspectRatio attribute on the root <svg> element. What's it set to? try preserveAspectRatio="none"

Comment: @MrLister Yes, the widths of the 'a' elements are set to 28.3% of the parent nav.

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried adding preserveAspectRatio="none" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Without seeing tab.svg it's hard to get any further here.

Comment: Here is the tab.svg: `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 957 286" style="enable-background:new 0 0 957 286;" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path id="Selector" style="opacity:0.5;" d="M0.5,0.351l0.042,0.083c68.195,1.743,84.244,55.248,97.075,124.907l28.816,124.17
 c3.923,19.925,16.566,36.839,36.814,36.839h628.131c20.248,0,33.468-16.507,36.814-36.839h-0.009L857,125.342
 c13.045-70.825,29.376-124.99,100.5-124.99H0.5z"/>
</svg>
`

Comment: @Akatsuki777 Can you edit the question and put that in?

Comment: @Akatsuki777 Anyway, with a width of 28.3% and a background-size of contain, yes, the background will size with the screen size. Either give the links a fixed width, or use another value for background-size.

Comment: @MrLister I changed the background size to 100% 100%, the problem seems to occur due to the other anchor elements' text-wrapping at lower screen sizes.